# How to authenticate in servicestack using angular spa basic authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication, servicestack, single-page-application

I have single page app and service stack as service on different domain name (cors). what is correct way to authenticate angular spa app?

Answer (score 1):

[TechStacks](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks) is an example of an AngularJS App that supports [Twitter and Facebook Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/d1e08cf8426faf41f62178286d23c0c5c53e538d/src/TechStacks/TechStacks/AppHost.cs#L61-L65).

Another minimal example of a Single Page App that has a number of different AuthProviders enabled is [AWS Auth](http://awsapps.servicestack.net/awsauth/), whilst the HttpBenchmarks example provides good documentation walking through setting up [Authentication + Registration](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#authentication) in ServiceStack.